# PL/SQL before insert trigger to prohibit insertion of two records that have age greater than 10 years

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

The BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER has to do the following:

- prohibits the assignment of two patients to the same room where the    difference in their ages is greater than 10 years.
- In addition, the trigger should also prohibit two patients with allowable ages (less or equal to 10) from being assigned to the same bed.

That means:

- If a new patient is about 10 year greater than any patient already admitted, they cannot be in the same room.
- If  a new patient is less than 10 year from any patient already admitted, they can be in the same room but not same bed.

Patient table structure:

```
   PAT_ID         CHAR
   PAT_NAME       CHAR
   PAT_GENDER     CHAR
   PAT_AGE        NUMBER
   PAT_ADMIT_D    CHAR
   PAT_WING       CHAR
   PAT_ROOM#      NUMBER
   PAT_BED        CHAR
```

So far my code is:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER assignmentcheck 
   before insert on patient
   for each row

   declare
        cursor p1_cursor is
             select pat_age, pat_room#, pat_bed from patient;

   agediff number;
   begin

        for p1_pat in p1_cursor loop
        agediff :=  p1_pat.pat_age - :new.pat_age;
        if (agediff >10) then
             if (:new.pat_room# = p1_pat.pat_room#) then
             raise_application_error(-20001, 'Age difference greater than 10     cannot be in the same room');
        end if;
        else if (:new.pat_room# = p1_pat.pat_room#) and (:new.pat_bed =  p1_pat.pat_bed) then
        raise_application_error(-20002, 'Age difference less than 10 cannot be on the same bed');
        end if;
        end if;
  end loop;

 end;
 /
```

Some test sql:

```
 insert into patient values ('AZ24523', 'Zhou, Alicia', 'F', 24, '14-APR-2015', 'A', 20, 'B');
 insert into patient values ('JA33234', 'Abbott, John', 'M', 50, '14-APR-2015', 'A', 16, 'B');
 insert into patient values ('AN32676', 'Newman, Andrew', 'M', 10, '14-APR-2015', 'A', 16, 'B');
 insert into patient values ('ZZ24523', 'Zhang, Zhaoping', 'F', 38, '14-APR-2015', 'A', 16, 'A');
```

The trigger supposes to compare a new row to rows already existed in the table. But so far my trigger has been comparing between new rows only and not with those who are already in the table.

How do I make it work as expected? I have been searching everywhere but can't find anyway to compare to the whole table/database.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Unrelated, but: I'm almost certain that you do **not** want the `char` datatype due to it's fixed length size and padding. Use `varchar` instead

Comment: I know hospital overcrowding is a big issue, but more than one patient per bed?  Really?

Comment: This is just how the question is created, definitely not something happen in real life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Good news:** Your trigger works (not fully but almost).

I don't know what you mean by: *But so far my trigger has been comparing between new rows only and not with those who are already in the table.*
Your trigger evidently checks already existing rows in table. It works properly. Of course if you create table, insert some conflicting rows 
and next you create the trigger it will not correct previous inserts - they have to be eliminated some other way (deleted or updated).

**Bad news:** your trigger will not work if you will try to insert several rows in one select, like here, you will get error `SQL Error: ORA-04091: table CHRIS.PATIENT is mutating, trigger/function may not see it`:

```
insert into patient  
  select 'AZ24523', 'Zhou',   'F', 24, '2015-04-14', 'A', 20, 'B' from dual union all
  select 'JA33234', 'Abbott', 'M', 50, '2015-04-14', 'A', 16, 'B' from dual union all
  select 'AN32676', 'Newman', 'M', 10, '2015-04-14', 'A', 16, 'B' from dual union all
  select 'ZZ24523', 'Zhang',  'F', 38, '2015-04-14', 'A', 16, 'A' from dual;
```

**What can be done in this situation?** In Oracle 11g you can change your code to [compound trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS2005):

```
create or replace trigger assignmentcheck 
for insert on patient compound trigger

  type patients_t is table of patient%rowtype;
  v_patients patients_t := patients_t();
  v_patient patient%rowtype;

before statement is begin
  select * bulk collect into v_patients from patient; 
end before statement;

before each row is begin
  v_patients.extend;
  v_patients(v_patients.last).pat_id := :new.pat_id;
  v_patients(v_patients.last).pat_age := :new.pat_age;
  v_patients(v_patients.last).pat_room# := :new.pat_room#;
  v_patients(v_patients.last).pat_bed := :new.pat_bed;
end before each row;

after each row is begin
  for i in 1..v_patients.count() loop
    v_patient := v_patients(i);
    if v_patient.pat_id<>:new.pat_id then 
      if v_patient.pat_room# = :new.pat_room# then 
        if abs(v_patient.pat_age-:new.pat_age) > 10 then 
          raise_application_error(-20001, 'Age difference to big');
        elsif v_patient.pat_bed = :new.pat_bed then
          raise_application_error(-20002, 'Bed already taken');
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;
  end loop;
end after each row;

end assignmentcheck;
```

In previous Oracle version you can use one of the solutions discuted in this article: [Mutating Table Exceptions](http://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/mutating-table-exceptions.php).

Comment: Ah, sorry, this is simple - just change condition for age, use function `abs` like in my trigger... `if abs(agediff)>10`... it should help.

Comment: Awesome! Function **abs()** does actually solve my issue. I think the problem comes from negative age when I subtract the age. Sorry I can't vote your answer up due to lack of reputation, but thanks for helping me.

Comment: But you can accept answer ;-) And aren't you afraid of this 'mutating table' error? 
Also I think that maybe you should add condition for wing, because there may be rooms 101 in wing A and room 101 in wing B.

Comment: How do you click to accept an answer? Sorry im new to stackoverflow. About the mutating error, i have tested with about 20 inserts but i didnt get the error message. I dont know why.

Comment: There is [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on Stack Overflow explaining this, I never asked questions so I don't know ;-) Mutating error occurs when you insert values as select, like in my example.

Comment: I put every insert on each line in a sql file and run that file to insert all those lines, so maybe thats why I dont get the mutating error. And I accepted the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks. So much words for this small `abs()` ;-) Anyway remember that some day ORA-04091 may happen.

Answer (score 1):

Relational databases make it easy to define 1-1 relationships, 1-many relationships and many-many relationships. The choices are zero, one or any-number-more-than-one. It's not so easy to define, say, a 1-2 relationship.

Here's one idea. First a table to define each room. There is one entry for each room.

```
create table Rooms(
    ID    int  identity,
    ... -- other room-related data
    constraint PK_Rooms primary key( ID )
);
```

Next a table to define the beds in each room. There is one entry for each bed of each room.

```
create table Room_Beds(
    RoomID int not null,
    BedID  smallint not null,
    constraint PK_Room_Beds primary key( RoomID, BedID ),
    constraint FK_Room_Beds_Room foreign key( RoomID )
        references Beds( ID )
);
```

Tables `Rooms` and `Room_Beds`, once defined, are stable. Their contents remain fixed during the day-to-day operations. The next table keeps a complete history of bed use. An entry is inserted when it is occupied and another when it becomes unoccupied. Note that an entry for BedID 3 (or higher) cannot be entered if only two beds have been defined for the room.

```
create table Bed_Patient(
    RoomID     int not null,
    BedID      smallint not null,
    StartDate  date not null,
    PatientID  int,
    IsOccupied as case when PatientID is null then 'N' else 'Y' end,
    constraint PK_Bed_Patient primary key( RoomID, BedID, StartDate )
);
```

Technically, there is nothing to stop the same bed from being "occupied" here during the same time period. This is prevented programmatically by only selecting beds for occupation from this view:

```
create view Available_Beds as
select  rb.*
from    Room_Beds rb
join    Bed_Patient bp
    on  bp.RoomID = rb.ID
    and bp.IsOccupied = 'N'
    and bp.StartDate =(
        select  Max( Start_Date )
        from    Bed_Patient
        where   RoomID = bp.RoomID
            and BedID  = bp.BedID );
```

Now an Insert trigger on `Bed_Patient` can check that the bed is listed in the view if the PatientID is not null, or is *not* listed if PatientID is null.

Timing must be handled, but that's pretty much a given for most applications. This is helped by the fact that as soon as a row is inserted in `Bed_Patient` with a non-null value in the PatientID field, that room no longer appears in the `Available_Beds` view.